# How to find the radius for a perfect semi-circular edge of a TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can do the following to have a TextField with rounded edges in Flutter.

```
TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

The edges are now rounded, but not sure whether they are perfect semi-circle.

How can I have the edges with perfect semi-circle?

(I guess I have to adjust the radius provided in the code, but how to find the exact radius to provide?)

Comment: Actually, there is no perfect radius for semi circle. Because if you increase hight then the radius will change. So, you just need to try with different radius and check what fit's in your app.

Comment: Textfield's Default height is around 45-50 px. So in order to get perfect semi arc just divide default height by 2

Answer (score 1):

The [default height of `TextField` is 48](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42449). So you can use `borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48 / 2),`. But there is default padding you need to count, `EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 8, 12, 8)` or `12` if the dense is true. So the perfect semi-circle can be seen

```dart
SizedBox(
  width: 48, // just to represent the circle 
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // just to represent the circle 
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48 / 2),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

You can create custom border by extending the `OutlineInputBorder`

Comment: I do want to keep the default padding.

Comment: use `contentPadding` as I've included

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a perfect semicircle, you can follow this method

1. Find the height of the `TextField`. Default height is 48px (when `isDense == false`).
2. `radius >= height/2`. For any radius value greater than half of the TextField height, you will get perfect semicircle edges. So, give any value greater than or equal to 24.

Comment: Any technical or documental proof for default is 48px?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42449.
For more info - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41200.

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
  width: 48, // just to represent the circle 
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // just to represent the circle 
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48 / 2),
      ),
      focusBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48 / 2),
      ),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48 / 2),
      ),
      enableBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48 / 2),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hi, your answer could be improved with an explanation of the code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SizedBox(
  width: 48, // just to represent the circle 
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, // just to represent the circle 
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      focusBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
      // error with validation data null
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),

      // enable border
      enableBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.